# select value with update ON DUPLICATE KEY query

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO table_online (IP,ID,field_test) 
VALUES('0','269','0')
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE IP = VALUES(IP),ID = '0';
```

Is it possible with this single query to return the value of `field_test`? Maybe to store it in a variable somehow?

Comment: You can add `field_test = @ft:=field_test` to your update list.

Comment: I would not recommend to use assignment in such kind of issues. That's because, in terms of concurring connections (single-session) that would be completely unsafe. Better to start transaction & get desired value inside it

Comment: If field_test is the auto increment primary key then you could update it with field_test=LAST_INSERT_ID(field_test), then it can be returned was the last inserted id.

Comment: Vatev, I tried that but it doesnt work? can you post the full query?

Comment: Alma Do , the value of that field is not that important , just as extra information. Im after the value BEFORE transaction, as you see with this query its not updating the column `field_test`